# Free video editor for Mac, with MPG/MKV support

Tags: osx, video-editing, macos, mkv

I want to do some basic video editing on Mac:

- Import a few video files of the same height/width
- Cut portions of each file and gather them to make a new video
- Export it as a new video file

Requirements:

- Can import both MPG and [MKV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroska) directly, without having to use any other software to convert first to a third format
- Can import files up to 2 GB
- Gratis
- Graphical interface to select video sequences, with either miniatures or frame preview
- Runs on Mac Catalina (and above)

*Note: iMovie is not a solution, because it can not import MPG and MKV.*

Answer (score 1):

Davinci Resolve is free, fantastic and works on mac. I have found it comparable to sony vegas, premier pro and final cut pro. Go for Resolve 16 and not the studio edition.

Comment: Unfortunately Davinci Resolve can not import .mkv files. Which is a central requirement of the question. Or is there a plugin to support MKV?

Comment: I had forgotten, yes you are correct. I personally am happy to remux my MKV files using "Avidemux" into MP4 before importing them into Davinci. You don't loose any quality and I don't personally find it very time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

Avidemux can do all of this.

- Can read MPG and MKV and many others
- Can import big files
- Gratis, even open source
- Super easy interface, really perfect for cutting/gathering. No thumbnails unfortunately, but frame preview
- Runs on Mac/Linux/Windows

Additionally:

- Select "copy" and it will:

  - Not lose any quality
  - Be very size efficient, basically the same bitrate as the original
  - Create the file very quickly
  - You need to cut only at key frame though
- Very small installer size compared to competitors
- Installable via `brew cask install avidemux` or normal download

[image]